# Broadcast an audio stream

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, broadcast

I'm building a c# application that caputures subtitles from TV-channels.
The purpose of this is  that visual impared persons are able to hear the translation.

I've managed to capture and convert the subtitles to a memory stream using directshow.
Now i have a memory stream with the spoken subtitles.

This stream needs to be broadcasted to devices that can read PLS, M3U or ASX playlists. They support MP3 by http, WMA by http and MMS.

I'm really stuck atm..

I've tried Microsoft Expression encoder, but it doesn't seem to support memory-streams as input, only capture  devices and files..

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can easily use SHOUTcast for the server side of this, once you get it all encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a look at either the [Windows Media Encoder SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=000a16f5-d62b-4303-bb22-f0c0861be25b), or [BASS.NET](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html).

BASS.NET is extremely useful for anything audio/streaming based within the .NET framework. - I've successfully used it to stream audio before and there are a lot of examples floating around for BASS.NET too.

BASS.NET is free to use for non-profit, and cheap licenses if it's a commercial project.

Hope this helps.